# How to redeploy nodejs server in modulus without facing downtime?

Tags: node.js, deployment, modulus.io

I have a node js server running at modulus.io. How can I redeploy the latest version of the server without facing downtime ?

Answer (score 1):

Modulus builds your app using a new container every time you deploy, so the switching can be as quick as a few milliseconds.

From their [docs](https://help.modulus.io/customer/en_us/portal/articles/1957328-how-modulus-works#run):

> Since the bundle is already built, making the switchover from the old
>   version of your application to the new is very quick. The process is:
>
> 1. Send graceful shutdown request to old application.
> 2. Stop the old application instance.
> 3. Remove the old application instance.
> 4. Extract new application instance.
> 5. Start the new application instance.
>
> Under normal conditions, the actual switchover takes a few
>   milliseconds. The amount of time it takes the application to start
>   serving requests then depends on how long it takes your application to
>   startup.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, Modulus currently deploys to all servos simultaneously so the server will inevitably go down for a few seconds while it starts.